# Can Swift code embed in existing Objective-C file - or must one add that code to a discrete Swift file?

Tags: objective-c, swift, embed

I have an Objective-c file which used to work with the older XCode's

with the emergence of XCode 6.x - code no longer performs

I found the same functionality in code written in Swift online

I read Apple's documentation about using bridging header's to allow the use of Swift with Objective-C. I was able to get that setup ok, I do believe.

What is not clear is - can I simply cut and paste the Swift code into my Objective-C file (a viewcontroller.me file actually), or am I limited to having to use a Swift file from the start ?

If I have to use a new file in my (very simple) app, Im not quite sure how to pull off having two viewcontroller.m files do the work where one used to work fine, so this method obviously creates a new problem for me.

Thanks for your assistance in advance !

Comment: No, you have to create a separate swift file for that class.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend just creating a class or struct for your swift code, and access that class or struct in your Objective-C ViewController.